# Name of upper row of options displayed in black

Tags: ios, uikit

I've seen this example of how to show different options when tapping and holding on a cell. I know it's silly to ask, but it's something you don't normally use and I can't come up with the name of it in UIKit.

[image]

Anyone knows the name of component?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Edit Menus" - https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/controls/edit-menus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `UIMenuController` and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614950-tableview

Here's example in Obj-C

```
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
UIMenuItem *deleteAction = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DELETE" action:@selector(deleteMessage:)];
[menu setMenuItems:@[deleteAction]];
```

Also, make sure this method is implemented:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 canPerformAction:(SEL)action
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       withSender:(id)sender
{
    return YES;
}
```